# MySQL statement to fetch a record based on multiple conditions through relational tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, activerecord

I am generating a query that returns a set of profiles that meet all the conditions posted below

I am receiving the data like so in Ruby, then making a dynamic MySQL query based on the contents -

```
[{ attribute_id: 58, parent_profile_name: 'Douglas-Connelly' },
{ attribute_id: 26, parent_profile_name: 'Brekke LLC' },
{ attribute_id: 35, val: 'Asa' },
{ attribute_id: 38, val: 'Stanton' }]
```

These are the current contents of the database

```
profile_attribute_values 
profile_id  attribute_id    parent_profile_id   val
6           58              2
6           26              5
6           35              nil                 'Asa'
6           38              nil                 'Stanton'

profile
id     name
2      Douglas-Connelly 
5      Brekke LLC
6      nil
```

I need to return all profiles that meet all the conditions - **profiles** that have a relation to **profile_attribute_values**, where the attribute_id is x, and the val is y, AND where the attribute_id is x, and the parent_profile name = y

**WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE**

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT P2. * 
FROM profile_attribute_values PAV
INNER JOIN profiles P1 ON P1.id = PAV.parent_profile_id
INNER JOIN profiles P2 ON P2.id = PAV.profile_id
WHERE (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '58' AND P1.`name` = 'Douglas-Connelly')
) A,

(SELECT P1. * 
FROM profiles P1
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAV ON P1.id = PAV.profile_id
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAV2 ON P1.id = PAV2.profile_id
WHERE (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '35' AND PAV.val = 'ASA')
AND (PAV2.ne_attribute_id = '38' AND PAV2.val = 'Stanton')
) B

WHERE A.id = B.id
```

This will return

```
profile
id    name
6     nil
```

which is exactly what I want, though the tricky part is the second parent_profile condition where I need attribute_id 26, and parent_profile_name: 'Brekke LLC'

I know this wont work, but I need this to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT P2. * 
FROM profile_attribute_values PAV
INNER JOIN profiles P1 ON P1.id = PAV.parent_profile_id
INNER JOIN profiles P2 ON P2.id = PAV.profile_id
WHERE (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '58' AND P1.`name` = 'Douglas-Connelly')
AND (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '26' AND P1.`name` = 'Brekke LLC')
) A,
.....
```

I am generating the SQL statement dynamically, so I really need it to be as clean as possible. I generally use ruby active record for everything, so I am a little babied when it comes to SQL statements. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Okay I found a great solution to generate the dynamic query that I need, makes a single call to the database. This is the finished class

```
class ProfileSearch
  def initialize(params, args = {})
    @attr_vals = params
    @options = args
    filter_attrs
  end

  attr_accessor :parent_attrs, :string_attrs

  def search
    Profile.joins(generate_query)
  end

  def generate_query
    q = ''
    q << parents_query
    q << attr_vals_query
  end

  def parents_query
    str = ''
    parent_attrs.each_with_index do |pa, i|
      str <<  "INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVP#{i} ON profiles.id = PAVP#{i}.profile_id "\
              "AND PAVP#{i}.ne_attribute_id = #{pa} "\
              "INNER JOIN profiles PP#{i} ON PP#{i}.id = PAVP#{i}.parent_profile_id "\
              "AND PP#{i}.`name` = '#{@attr_vals[pa.to_s]}' "
    end
    str
  end

  def attr_vals_query
    str = ''
    string_attrs.each_with_index do |a, i|
      str << "INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVS#{i} ON profiles.id = PAVS#{i}.profile_id "\
             "AND PAVS#{i}.ne_attribute_id = #{a} AND PAVS#{i}.val = '#{@attr_vals[a.to_s]}' "
    end
    str
  end

  def filter_attrs
    ne = NeAttribute.find(@attr_vals.keys)
    self.parent_attrs = ne.select{ |x| x.parent_profile)_attr? }.map(&:id)
    self.string_attrs = ne.select{ |x| x.string_attr? }.map(&:id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know about is `joins`.

Use it like so:

```
relation_1 =  ProfileAttributeValue.joins("
  INNER JOIN profiles P1 ON P1.id = PAV.parent_profile_id
  INNER JOIN profiles P2 ON P2.id = PAV.profile_id
").where(..).pluck(:id)

relation_2 = ProfileAttributeValue.joins...where...pluck(:id)
```

relation_1 and relation_2 have not yet been run. They are ActiveRecord relations.

I like the following trick:

```
ProfileAttributeValue.where(["profile_attribute_values.id in (?) or profile_attribute_values.id in (?)]", relation_1, relation_2)
```

Again, that's just an activerecord relation. Call `to_sql` on it if curious. 
Add more `.where` or whatever, and when run, it'll be a single query on the DB.

Comment: Good call on the joins method, though this still creates multiple queries, and its not getting exactly what I need, due to the self join on a separate instance of the profiles table. I really need for this to be as optimized as possible as its being called a lot. I actually did figure out though, see update above.

Answer (score 1):

Posting what I did as the answer, in case anyone misses it above. This essentially creates a single joins query that allows me to pull the exact data needed. The query generated would look like this -

```
SELECT `profiles`.* 
FROM `profiles` 
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVP0 ON profiles.id = PAVP0.profile_id 
    AND PAVP0.ne_attribute_id = 26 
INNER JOIN profiles PP0 ON PP0.id = PAVP0.parent_profile_id 
    AND PP0.`name` = 'Brekke LLC' 
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVP1 ON profiles.id = PAVP1.profile_id 
    AND PAVP1.ne_attribute_id = 58 
INNER JOIN profiles PP1 ON PP1.id = PAVP1.parent_profile_id 
    AND PP1.`name` = 'Douglas-Connelly' 
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVS0 ON profiles.id = PAVS0.profile_id 
    AND PAVS0.ne_attribute_id = 35 AND PAVS0.val = 'Asa' 
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVS1 ON profiles.id = PAVS1.profile_id 
    AND PAVS1.ne_attribute_id = 38 AND PAVS1.val = 'Stanton'
```

This is the class that generates its

```
class ProfileSearch
  def initialize(params, args = {})
    @attr_vals = params
    @options = args
    filter_attrs
  end

  attr_accessor :parent_attrs, :string_attrs

  def search
    Profile.joins(generate_query)
  end

  def generate_query
    q = ''
    q << parents_query
    q << attr_vals_query
  end

  def parents_query
    str = ''
    parent_attrs.each_with_index do |pa, i|
      str <<  "INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVP#{i} ON profiles.id = PAVP#{i}.profile_id "\
              "AND PAVP#{i}.ne_attribute_id = #{pa} "\
              "INNER JOIN profiles PP#{i} ON PP#{i}.id = PAVP#{i}.parent_profile_id "\
              "AND PP#{i}.`name` = '#{@attr_vals[pa.to_s]}' "
    end
    str
  end

  def attr_vals_query
    str = ''
    string_attrs.each_with_index do |a, i|
      str << "INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAVS#{i} ON profiles.id = PAVS#{i}.profile_id "\
             "AND PAVS#{i}.ne_attribute_id = #{a} AND PAVS#{i}.val = '#{@attr_vals[a.to_s]}' "
    end
    str
  end

  def filter_attrs
    ne = NeAttribute.find(@attr_vals.keys)
    self.parent_attrs = ne.select{ |x| x.parent_profile)_attr? }.map(&:id)
    self.string_attrs = ne.select{ |x| x.string_attr? }.map(&:id)
  end
end
```